# Importing Git project to Eclipse Workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, git

Deleted Eclipse Workspace data, only the Workspace related info and not my projects and need to import back a Git Project into the workspace again.
How do I do that without losing out on all my Git info on the project.

Will it suffice if I again import my project into the workspace and start working back on it?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: You have deleted it just in Eclipse, nothing in your repo. So importing it again, it would be in the same status that is in your repo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can just add the project back to eclipse with the new project wizard pointing to the location of the existing project.

If it does not pick up the git configuration automatically you can add it with the *Git Repositories* view  *Add existing local repository*, again pointing to the project location.

Comment: Thanks :D
Was just being cautious :)

Comment: well, you could always just make a backup copy and experiment. practically no risk.